# Is testing for endogeneity necessary?

Tags: least-squares, sas, heteroscedasticity, endogeneity

I was wondering if testing for endogeneity is necessary when doing an OLS multiple regression.

Similarly, is testing for autocorrelation necessary if there is no time series data?

Is testing for heteroscedasticity necessary, or is it something you can estimate by looking at graphs?

Thanks if you have any pointers. I am clearly not very adept at econometrics, and just trying to finish a project. I already have very low confidence in my model, so does it matter if I do these other tests? I am using SAS and it's giving me a ton of problems already.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if testing for endogeneity is necessary when doing an OLS multiple regression.

It's not necessary unless you suspect that it may be present. If you do, then it's not only necessary, but you also have to do something about it.

> Similarly, is testing for autocorrelation necessary if there is no time series data?

No. You need serial data to run this test. Note, that it doesn't need to be time dimension, but as long as your observations are ordered in some way, autocorrelation maybe present. For instance, if you're measuring something along the physical dimension, then adjacent observations may be correlated. This may mess up your model.

> Is testing for heteroscedasticity necessary, or is it something you can estimate by looking at graphs?

It's not required, but if you're looking at certain regression diagnostics or testing hypothesis, then it is often assumed that the errors are homoscedastic, so you might as well test for it.